# DNN New skin causes login to fail

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I'm not proficient in ASP or DNN, but it was assigned to me at work, so I'm pushing through it.

I duplicated a skin on the site and chose it as the active skin, then tore out some of it's "guts" and simply wanted one content block.  It was working until I changed the content, now when I try to login as host, it comes back with `Login Failed. Please remember that passwords are case sensitive`.

Is it possible that I ripped something out that was necessary for it to function? The AJAX call seems to be fine.

*Update:* I added the login/register links back, and when I clicked on the login link to bring up the form in a modal, logging in from there worked. Weird.

*Update 2:* I looked at the two AJAX calls, the one from the modal window included

```
dnn$ctr$Login$Login_DNN$txtUsername=sdhost
&
dnn$ctr$Login$Login_DNN$txtPassword=<password>
```

whereas the form from `Login.aspx` did not.

Comment: When you clicked on the login link in the skin, did it load a different page, with a different skin? Or the same "new" skin you created?

Comment: @ChrisHammond it's all in the same skin - the new one I created.